# How to decompose a page in several view with Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

How does any body know how to divide a single html page in different view with angular.js.

I have this working :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecat">
<head>
 ....
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

But i would like to do something like this :

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="phonecat">
<head>
 ....
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view Sidebar></div>
  <div ng-view></div>
 <div ng-view Footer></div>
</body>
</html>
```

In advance thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular UI router should be a newer better way to handle this problem.  At least that's its goal, and it looks very promising, but I haven't used it yet myself.

Angular UI is restructuring their site right now, so the links are a little scattered:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki

http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/#/

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is "ng-include" : http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude